# if i upload image,'no files selected' message is showing up

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, file-upload

I am using following HTML code for file upload

```
<input type="file" nv-file-select="" ng-accept="'*.gif,*.jpg,*.png,*.jpeg'" filters="queueLimit" multiple="" uploader="images">
```

After uploading image it still shows the message `no files selected`. how can I remove this text after image upload.

Please help

Comment: Is your file uploaded to server?

Answer (score 0):

You mean after upload, when the input field has been resetted again? This is browsers built in way of handling things and you cannot do much about it. You can hide the input completely though - and trigger the upload with another button.

Comment: Can you please suggest some example?